# Eclipse Wizard OSGI Bundle Project

Tags: maven, javafx, osgi, equinox

i have a question regarding one of the Eclipse e(fx)clipse plugin wizards [OSGI Bundle Project] what is the meaning of the four project

```
test.app
test.app.feature
test.app.product
test.app.releng
```

what is the expected functionallity of each one of these (folders)?
is it related to Maven?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've described on my blog http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/12/10/my-recommended-project-structure-for-javafx-e4-projects/ the structure we advice to follow and the wizard exactly produces this structure, it is not mandatory so if you think it makes no sense then you are free to come up with something different, the tooling nor anything else depends on the setup!